# How to download all the QTP scripts from HPQC?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

I want to download all the QTP scripts folder wise to my local system. Currently all the scripts are stored in ALM.
Path ->Test plan->Folder->Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program to use the Open Test API (OTA). This code below is based on C++ using the #import wrappers for the OTA.

Given an ITest2Ptr you can determine if it is a QTP script with:

```
if (test->Type == "QUICKTEST_TEST")
{
/* ... */
}
```

You can save the test script using:

```
IExtendedStoragePtr storage = test->ExtendedStorage;
BSTR raw_root_path;
HRESULT hr = storage->raw_Load(L"", VARIANT_TRUE, &raw_root_path);
```

The 'raw_root_path' folder contains all the QTP related material.